# Adding a failable initializer with the same signature as super class's convenience initializer (Swift)

Tags: swift, swift2

I would like to know why I cant define `init?()` for `SubView`. Compiler warms me with `Failable initializer 'init()' cannot override a non-failable initializer`. But for my understanding `convenience init` is not treat as `override` in subclass as compile will warm me if I add `override` to `init?()` with `Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass`.

My expectation for SubView.init?() is that it should not treat as a override to View.init() as SubView should not have that convenience initializer inherited as SubView.init() in the first place.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class View {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    init(frame: CGRect) {

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    }
}

class SubView: View {
    private var value: String!

    init?() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Objective-C was so much freedom... it would come back and bite you every once in a while, but as long as you knew what you were doing, you were good.  Swift, instead, requires that you be a **lawyer**  ;)

Comment: @NicolasMiari: On the contrary, I find Swift to be much more flexible, with it's type-inference and the fact that you don't need to add semi-colons to single line statements.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and mostly agree. I'm enjoying the new features of swift myself, 24/7 now. But swift also has so many more rules and restrictions, that getting used to it takes significant effort.

Comment: @NicolasMiari To compare Objective-C and Swift doesn't seem to be a good idea. It is like to compare Swahili and Chinese. To use Swift, we need to adopt our thinking and use the language for our advantage.

Comment: @user3441734 Actually, you can compare any two languages. I spent significant time using both and shared my impression of how different it feels to use each. That, and pretending to extend the Objective-C mindset into Swift (instead of learning the new "way") is a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this 'self explanatory' example

```
class Base {
    var i:Int
    init?(i: Int){
        self.i = i
        if i == 0 {
            return nil
        }
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init(i: 1)!
    }
}

class C: Base {
    override init?(i: Int){
        super.init(i: 2 * i)
    }
}

var c: C? = C() // C automatically inherits convenience init() from its superclass
c?.i == 2 // true !!!!!

// that is why
class D: Base {
    init?() {
        // error: failable initializer 'init()' cannot override a non-failable initializer
    }
}
```

UPDATE

from our discussion i think, that the 'missing glue' in proper understanding initialization in Swift is interpretation of '`convenience`' attribute / keyword. what is the difference between `init()` and `convenience init()` ? if we don't provide any designated initializer, Swift use the default one, which can be interpreted with signature `init(){}` /no parameters/. if we define our own version of `init(){ .... }`, compiler will use our version. in designated `init(){ ... }` or `init?(){ ... }` we are NOT able to reference `self`, in `convenience init(){ ... }` or `convenience init?() { ... }` we can and mostly we do it. Otherwise `convenience` is not necessary there. Which initializer could compiler to use, if we are going to define two of them with the same signature /same parameters/? There is no chance to choose for it!

```
// your expectation is wrong,
// because initializer is NOT like other methods

class C {
    var i: Int?
    // this compiles here, but see the usage below!
    func foo()->Int {
        i = 1
        return i!
    }
    func foo()->Int? {
        i = nil
        return i
    }
    // convenience or not, it doesn' matter
    init() {
        i = 1
    }

    // with next lines compiler complains
    // because they all have the same signature / same parameters /
    // from you code you call all three initializers
    // the same way
    //
    // let c = C()
    //
    // dynamicType of c depends of the relsut of class constructor (initializer).
    // this result is anyway the REFERENCE, not a value.
    // c will be a variable or constant (probably an optional) which value will
    // be the REFERNCE to created instance (and probably 'null reference')
    // nil is special value in Swift and differs from 'null reference'
    // in case of fail-able initializer the c must be Optional or ImplicitlyInwrappedOptional
/*
    convenience init?() {
        self.init()
    }
    init?() {
        return nil
    }
*/
}
let c = C()
let p1: Int = c.foo()  // 1
let p2: Int? = c.foo() // nil
//let p = c.foo() // error: ambiguous use of 'foo()'

class D {
    var i:Int?
    init() {
        i = 1
    }
}

// by the theory, compiler could be 'smart' enough to choose the
// right version of initializer, but it could have very strong
// consequences to the language as well.

let d1: D = D()
let d2: D? = D()
d1.i  // 1
d2?.i // 1

// but only one is valid if we use fail-able version of init
class E {
    var i:Int?
    init?() {
        i = 1
    }
}
let e1: E? = E()
e1?.i // 1
//let e2:E = E() // error: value of optional type 'E?' not unwrapped
```

Comment: I understand when subclass provided an implementation of all of its superclass’s designated initializers, subclass will automatically inherits all of its superclass’s convenience initializers too. But in my code snippet, my subclass does not provide all of its superclass’s designated initializers.

Comment: @MortyChoi do you see more designated initializer in class D? it is just one there and independent of what you try to call inside, it fails. from the compiler message  is clear why. And please see the line c?.i == 2 and try to understand why the value is 2 and not 1 (as convenience init() in class Base sets)

Comment: @MortyChoi var c = C() (in my example var c:C? = C()) gives you nonoptional value, where c.i == 2 It is clear, that it is NOT result of overriden init?()

Comment: Rule 2 of Automatic Initializer Inheritance : If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.

Comment: In my class SubView, I only provide one of the 2 superclass designated initializers. So the superclass convenience initializers should not be inherited. But the compiler still warming me that I am overriding. I think it is wired.

Comment: I understand that class D should been treat as overriding since it satisfy both rules of Automatic Initializer Inheritance.

Comment: @MortyChoi in that case you can understand that in your example SubView.init?() is not able to override convenience View.init(). the result (without subclassing) looks like class C { init(i: Int){}; convenience init(){ self.init(i: 1) }; init?(){} }. try it and you will see that you can have just ONE init?() or convenience init(), but never both together. by the way, convenience init?(){ self.init(i: 1) } can also be fail-able.

Comment: My expectation for SubView.init?() is that it should not treat as a override to View.init() as SubView should not have that convenience initializer inherited as SubView.init() in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99931/discussion-between-user3441734-and-morty-choi).